# GDMS (Grandstream API) POST request with axios

Tags: node.js, axios, voip, telephony

I am trying to make a POST request to the GDMS api.
I keep getting the error code: 4000, which means "signature not exists"

I first obtain the token and return `axios.create()`

```
exports.client = async () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve =>{
        axios.get('https://www.gdms.cloud/oapi/oauth/token', {
            params:{
                username: username,
                password: password,
                grant_type: grant_type,
                client_id: client_id,
                client_secret: client_secret
            }
        }).then(res=>{
            let client = axios.create({
                baseURL: 'https://www.gdms.cloud/oapi/v1.1.0',
                headers: {'authorization': `bearer${res.data.access_token}`}
            })
            return resolve(client)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error.message)
            return resolve(false)
        })
    }))
}
```

That works fine.

Then I call the endpoint `/sip/servers/list` like so

> await gdms.sipServers.list(client)

```
exports.list = async (client) =>{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let timestamp = new Date().toISOString()
        client.post('/sip/server/list',{
            timestamp: timestamp,
            signature: sha256(`&timestamp=${timestamp}&`)
        }).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
            return resolve(res.data)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error.message)
            return resolve(false)
        })
    })
}
```

But I keep getting the same error "signature not exists"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the documents for the signature
https://doc.grandstream.dev/GDMS-API/EN/#api-157061470296601000002

Comment: what grant_type did you use? I am using grant_type password but getting error {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
} although my username, password,client_id, client_secret is correct?

Comment: invalid_grant error was resolved by passing encrypted password as mentioned in the doc

Comment: It's been awhile.. but I will be revisiting this soon.